# Measure feature length of a shapefile that falls within boundaries of polygon layers of a different shapefile

Tags: qgis

I use Qgis 2.18.6

I have a vector layer with roads. These are of two types, new and existing roads, in the same shapefile.Those roads, on the map cross over different propertys (propertys of land).

I have a raster layer from a different shapefile with those property lines.

I want to know how long the roads are on each of the propertys. Preferably as a table.

Comment: That worked a dream, thanx a lot!

Comment: Most welcome! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Run the **Intersection** tool using your roads layer and polygon layer.
2. Then for the output, run the **Field Calculator**, create a new *real* field and use the expression:

   ```
   $length
   ```

   to calculate the length of each feature.